# Como obter mês atual com getDisplayName

Tags: java, android

Pretendo obter o mês atual e para isso estou a utilizar o seguinte código:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String mes = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

O problema é que por exemplo agora em vez de me devolver `April` está a devolver-me `March`.

Alguém pode ajudar a perceber o que estou a colocar mal no `getDisplayName`?

Comment: Já chegou a testar o `SimpleDateFormat` com o `Locale`? Acho que essa pergunta pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string.

Comment: @Wakim, Eu só uso o Locale para colocar o mês em Inglês.

Comment: A data do sistema está correta?

Comment: @ramaral, sim está correcta

Answer (score 1):

Executando o exemplo acima, não obtive erro algum, retornou o mês correto.
Antes de executar o código, verifique se a data do sistema em que a JVM está rodando está correta.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;


public class Testes {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String mes = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println("Mes: " + mes);

    mes = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println("Mes: " + mes);
}

}
```

O Output ficou assim:

```
Mes: April
Mes: April
```